# How to show full string on a DataGridPro cell instead of ellipsizing the string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I went through the whole [DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) documentations and couldn't figure out how we can display sting in multiple lines without ellispis inside a cell. This is the behaviour i am getting:

[image]

This is how I wanted:

[image]

Th string should extend to the second line if it is too big to be displayed in a single line. I have added `width`, `minWidth` and `maxWidth` column properties to this column. These are the properties of the column:

```
field: item.name,
headerName: item.display,
hide: item.hidden
width: 200, 
minWidth: 50, 
maxWidth: 300
```

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this property to the DataGrid solved the issue:

```
getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
```